# Strings in list of classes returning null

Tags: class, flutter

```
 class Q {
  String que;
  bool qa;
  Q({String q1, bool q2}) {
    que = q1;
    qa = q2;
  }
}


 List<Q> qu = [
Q(q1: 'You can lead a cow downstairs but not upstairs.',q2: false,),
Q(q1: 'YAML Ain't Markup Language', q2: true,),
]

   print(qu[0].que)
```

returns null. why?
I want it to return the string.
But instead, it's returning null. The class Q has a separate dart file of its own which I'm importing using:

```
import 'q.dart';
```

The rest of the code is in main.dart.

Comment: Is this your real code? It doesn't seem to be possible `qu.que` to print null with the code you show... the problem should be some place else. I assume this is just an example as it does not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should declare the type of qu :

```
Q qu = Q(
  q1: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.',
  q2: false,
);
```

since qu is of type Q you can use the code above, otherwise you can use the keyword var (not recommend because dart is strongly statically typed)

```
var qu = Q(
  q1: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.',
  q2: false,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I test with your code, it works well...
But beacuse there is a error, you need to add a type for defining variable.

```
Q qu = Q(
      q1: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.',
      q2: false,
    )
```

[image]